# Jenkins Heroku Step war:deploy success, but build failed

Tags: jenkins, heroku

my jenkins runs on windows and I have a job, which checks out from git, then do mvn clean install, then the heroku-command

```
heroku war:deploy target\server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --app **APPNAME**
```

gets executed. The output is:

```
Uploading server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-----> Packaging application...
       - app: soccercomserver
       - including: webapp-runner.jar
       - including: target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
-----> Creating build...
       - file: slug.tgz
       - size: 18MB
-----> Uploading build...
       - success
-----> Deploying...
remote: 
remote: -----> heroku-deploy app detected
remote: -----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 68.7M
remote: -----> Launching...
remote:        Released v10
remote:        https://soccercomserver.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
remote: 
-----> Done
```

But the jenkins-job failes with the message

```
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I googled and found out that there is something like errorlevel in windows cmd. So I tried to figure out what happens, but with the command `echo Errorlevel: %ERRORLEVEL%`

i get no output, I guess because the CMD thinks it's a failure before it's get executed.

Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks and Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your command

```
heroku war:deploy target\server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war --app **APPNAME** --exit-code
```

It should return the error code.

Any error code other 0 will result in

> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

Solution

Fix the issue with heroku and ensure that you get 0 or if you are happy with the existing commands as it is, then just run another batch command like a dummy command which will return a 0 like

```
ver > nul
```